# SQLException: unclosed quotation mark but no quotation mark found

Tags: c#, sql, exception

unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'HD10'.

I have read a lot of solution for this error and it is clearly stated because of ('). However i have done search the greatness apostrophe in my sql.

```
select * from Voucher where VoucherNo like '%''%'
```

it came out nothing. This actually means something good. My data are great. But the bad news is, I still cant solve this.

I also did search any truncate or duplicate just, i dont know, hoping it shows somewhere even i know thats not what is about. And this shows no sign of truncate nor duplicate.

If anyone really knows something (beside of giving the same advice to do what i already done), it would help a lot. Thank you.

-----EDITTED-------

this is my program code

```
public override VoucherCollection GetVoucherWhere(string whereCondition)
    {
        VoucherCollection VoucherCollection = new VoucherCollection();
        Database db = SqlDataHelper.CreateConnection(_sqlConnectionString);
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_SELECT_Voucher_WHERE");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "whereExpression", DbType.String, " " + whereCondition);
        using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
```

**I dont think the error come from the codes, as this program have been running for 2 years. However, it only came right after my client running a new voucher for a bonus. (And the person who run this thing have already transferred to a different department)

> > The where statement shows all the voucherno in DB. 
> >     The dbcommand shows the exception.

im using sql server 2008

Comment: What version of SQL are you using, and what string are you trying to match?  Also, could you include the relevant .NET code, as there may be some escaping happening there as well?

Comment: Is this an exception raised when you run a query from C# code? If yes could you post the code that has this behavior?

Comment: the `like '%''%'` on one of my tables and there is no problem with it. Assuming you are searching for ONE single quote.

Comment: But maybe you have some hidden characters in the sql?

Comment: Could you show the value of `whereCondition` that leads to the error and maybe also some relevant details of `SP_SELECT_Voucher_WHERE`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     select * from Voucher where VoucherNo like '%''''%'
```

' is opening/closing string char so when you want ' in between string, you will

need escape sequence that is other ' char

for 2 ' chars, two esc char '

ie. ''''

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: The OP needs one (escaped) *single* quote to see if there are `VoucherNo` values containing a quote.